# For each links in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I've these two links

```
<a href="#">Hello world !</a>
<a href="#">About us</a>
```

I want to get their values so I did this

```
$('a').val();
```

Then I want that each link values goes into a span like this :

```
<span>Hello world !</span>
<span>About us</span>
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: First please explain what you consider a "value" of an anchor?

Answer (score 6):

loop through `<a>` by using `.each()` then get value for each `<a>` then append it to the element you need .. in my example I appended it to `<body>`

```js
$('a').each(function(){
  var value = $(this).text();
  $('body').append('<span>'+ value  +'</span>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Hello world !</a>
<a href="#">About us</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$("a").each(function(){
  var val = $(this).text();
  $("body").append("<span>" + val  +"</span>");
});
```

You loop through all of the anchor tags using [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/), grab their text, then stick that into a span element and append it to something (e.g. the body).

**Edit**: beaten to it :)